# Use of Atomic Shared Structures in D

Tags: variables, struct, d, atomic, shared

How do I make a word-sized `shared` variable atomic in D?

I'm currently looking at `core.atomic` but I don't see any wrapper template named something like atomic. Isn't the interface designed in the same way as C++11 atomic?

Answer (score 1):

no it only has load store and cas available but you can build your own wrappers with it

for example:

```
shared int sharedInt=0;

int getAndIncrement();
    return atomicOp!("+=")(&sharedInt,1)-1;
}
```

Comment: `int` is not word-size, it has a fixed size. `size_t` is (assuming target system uses word-size pointers)

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун but it will work on any type with sizeof 1,2,4 or 8 (thought the overloaded assign or equal is not used)

Comment: Just wanted to avoid possible further confusion because question author was asking about word size and in C++ `int` is word sized, but that is not the case in D.

Comment: An `int` is always 32bit/4byte signed in D. An 8byte value will not fit in there and unsigned 32bit neither.  Use `long`/`ulong` for 64bit values. Details: http://dlang.org/type.html